# Progressing fluent interfaces how can I hide all methods but one at the start?

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

Trying to create a simple noddy example so that I can build my next project using fluent interfaces.
I need to provide the user of my dll with an intuitive step by step way of building a class.

Question.
I would like the user only to see Initialise when the first start then step1 then step2
and then end?How can I do it?

This is my attempt which As soon as you put the "." you see everything,then they hide.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnd builder = new StepBuilder()
            .Initialize()
            .LoadStuff()
            .Validate()
            .End();

    }
}
 public class StepBuilder : IInitialize,
                              IStep1,
                              IStep2,
                              IStep3,
                              IEnd
 {
     public IStep1 Initialize()
     {
         return this;
     }

     public IStep2 LoadStuff()
     {
         return this; ;
     }

     public IStep3 Validate()
     {
         return this;
     }

     public IEnd End()
     {
         return this;
     }

     public bool Save()
     {
         return true;
     }
 }

public class Step
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public interface IInitialize
{
    IStep1 Initialize();
}

public interface IStep1 
{
    IStep2 LoadStuff();
}

public interface IStep2 
{
    IStep3 Validate ();
}

public interface IStep3
{
    IEnd End();
}
public interface IEnd 
{
    bool Save();
}
```

}

any suggestions or good link on building progressive fluent interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn `Initialize()` into a static factory method, and make the constructor private.  Then your creation code would look like:

```
    IEnd builder = StepBuilder.Initialize()
         .LoadStuff()
         .Validate()
         .End();
```

A second idea, would be to make the interface implementations explicit.  Then you'd only see the methods for the interface you're dealing with at the time.

**Update**

Here's example code for both methods.  The interfaces are exactly the same as in your question.

Example with factory method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnd builder = StepBuilder
            .Initialize()
            .LoadStuff()
            .Validate()
            .End();

    }
}

public class StepBuilder : IInitialize,
                             IStep1,
                             IStep2,
                             IStep3,
                             IEnd
{
    private StepBuilder()
    {
    }

    public static IStep1 Initialize()
    {
        var builder = new StepBuilder();
        //do initialisation stuff
        return builder;
    }

    public IStep2 LoadStuff()
    {
        return this; 
    }

    public IStep3 Validate()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IEnd End()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example with explicit interface implementations:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnd builder = new StepBuilder()
            .Initialize()
            .LoadStuff()
            .Validate()
            .End();

    }
}

public class StepBuilder : IInitialize,
                             IStep1,
                             IStep2,
                             IStep3,
                             IEnd
{
    public IStep1 Initialize()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IStep2 IStep1.LoadStuff()
    {
        return this; 
    }

    public IStep3 IStep2.Validate()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IEnd IStep3.End()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool IEnd.Save()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply that sounds good.How would that change the rest of the interfaces? Does that mean my IStep1 Initialise will dissapear?

Comment: Just tried that but after that I see everything.I think I am missing the obvious.Any time for a small example using the interfaces I provided.Many thanks

Comment: @AndrewCooper.Again thanks for your time it was in front of my eyes and I could not see it.