# Enforce certain rules on fluent interface

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

I have created a fluent API which works as expected.
Now I would like to enforce some rules to make sure everything is built correct:

1: First method called should be `BuildTestPlan`, nothing else should be listed in intellisense *(==> now all is available --> Solved: see update)*

2: After `BuildTestPlan` only `AddTestSequence` should be available *(==> this is ok)*

3: After `AddTestSequence` only `AddTest` should be available *(==> this is ok)*

4: After `AddTest` there should be 3 options available: `AddTest` *( ==> this is ok)*, `AddTestSequence` *(==> here I'm stuck)* and `GetResult` *(==> this is ok)*

**Code:**

```
public class FluentTestPlanBuilderWithRules : ITestPlanBuilder, ITestSequenceBuilder, ITestBuilder
{
    public ITestSequenceBuilder BuildTestPlan()
    {
        // Do stuff
        return this;
    }

    public ITestBuilder AddTestSequence()
    {
        // Do stuff
        return this;
    }

    public ITestBuilder AddTest()
    {
        // Do stuff
        return this;
    }

    public TestPlan GetResult()
    {
        // Return built TestPlan
    }
}

public interface ITestPlanBuilder
{
    ITestSequenceBuilder BuildTestPlan();
}

public interface ITestSequenceBuilder
{
    ITestBuilder AddTestSequence();
}

public interface ITestBuilder
{
    ITestBuilder AddTest();
    TestPlan GetResult();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var builder = new EnforcedFluentTestPlanBuilder();
var o = builder.BuildTestPlan()
        .AddTestSequence()
        .AddTest()
        .AddTest()
        .AddTest()
        .AddTestSequence()
        .AddTest()
        .AddTest()
        .AddTestSequence()
        .AddTest()
        .GetResult();
```

I'm afraid there is no way to enforce nr 1 since they are all public methods.
But is it possible to have `AddTestSequence` both after `AddTest` and after `BuildTestPlan`?

**UPDATE:**
Found a solution for nr 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779736/progressing-fluent-interfaces-how-can-i-hide-all-methods-but-one-at-the-start)

Comment: For issue #4, have ITestBuilder inherit from ITestSequenceBuilder. Would that work for what you want?

Comment: @JaCraig this will make `AddTestSequence` also available after `AddTestSequence`, which should not be possible.

Comment: In that case create another interface that inherits from ITestBuilder and ITestSequenceBuilder and return that from ITestBuilder's AddTest method instead. Fluent interfaces are basically just like doing a FSM with interfaces, you just need another state/interface.

Comment: @JaCraig Nice 1! Works like a charm. You should add this as an answer.